# Линейный алгоритм проверка функции

Tags: c#

C# правильно ли написана у меня функция ? потому что при проверке не выдает нужные значения, хотя вроде всё правильно сделал, сам по себе новичок в C#

```cs
public static double Evaluate(string expression)
{
    System.Data.DataTable table = new System.Data.DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("expression", string.Empty.GetType(), expression);
    System.Data.DataRow row = table.NewRow();
    table.Rows.Add(row);
    return double.Parse((string)row["expression"]);
}
```

```cs
double x = Evaluate(textBox1.Text);
double y = Evaluate(textBox2.Text);
double z = Evaluate(textBox3.Text);
double a = Math.Exp(x-y) * Math.Pow(Math.Abs(x-y),x+y);
double b = Math.Atan(x) + Math.Atan(z);
double c = Math.Pow(Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(x,6)) +  Math.Pow(Math.Log(y),2),2/3);
double u = (a / b) + c;
textBox4.Text = "U = " + u;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `double c = Math.Pow(Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(x,6)) +  Math.Pow(Math.Log(y),2),2/3);` - это выражение не соответствует формуле

Comment: извините, а как правильно его сделать, я не понимаю, как правильно работать со степенями

Comment: ты правильно работаешь со степенями. Просто используешь какие-то другие значения, например 2/3 вместо 1/3. зачем=то вычисляешь квадратный корень, хотя в формуле его вообще нет

Comment: точно, изменил на 1/3, но всё равно, ответ не тот

Comment: есть вероятность, что в показателе у `e` тоже должен модуль стоять

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переменная `c` должна выглядеть так:

```cs
double c = Math.Cbrt(Math.Pow(x, 6) + Math.Pow(Math.Log(y), 2));
```

Либо если вы используете древний фреймворк 4.x, где нет кубического корня `Math.Cbrt`, то вот так:

```cs
double c = Math.Pow(Math.Pow(x, 6) + Math.Pow(Math.Log(y), 2), 1.0 / 3);
```

Обратите внимание:

```
1 / 3 = 0 - целочисленное деление
1.0 / 3 = 0.(3) - а тут всё норм
```

Кстати, @Grundy прав, `Math.Exp` надо возводить в степень по модулю.

```cs
double a = Math.Exp(Math.Abs(x-y)) * Math.Pow(Math.Abs(x-y), x+y);
```

Я проверил в консоли:

```cs
double x = -2.235E-2;
double y = 2.23;
double z = 15.221;

double a = Math.Exp(Math.Abs(x - y)) * Math.Pow(Math.Abs(x - y), x + y);
double b = Math.Atan(x) + Math.Atan(z);
double c = Math.Cbrt(Math.Pow(x, 6) + Math.Pow(Math.Log(y), 2));

double u = a / b + c;
Console.WriteLine("U = " + u);
```

Вывод в консоль:

```
U = 39.37412527565023
```

Кстати, метод `Evaluate` можно немного упростить:

```cs
public static double Evaluate(string expression)
{
    object result = DataTable.Compute(expression, string.Empty);
    return result is string s && double.TryParse(s, out double n) ? n : 0;
}
```

Такая реализация метода никогда не выдаст исключения. Опционально, если `0` в качестве результата по умолчанию не подходит, то можно заменить на `double.NaN`.

Comment: всё равно не подходит ответ, извините, а как модуль добавить ещё в экспоненту, дабы проверить, вдруг там модуль

Comment: @armb1ood `Math.Abs` же, но не уверен, что это вообще нужно. Обновите вопрос, покажите либо значения переменных перед вычислением, либо содержимое текстбоксов код метода `Evaluate`

Comment: обновил вопрос, добавил Evaluate

Comment: @armb1ood обновил ответ.

Comment: спасибо огромное